# MUI: how to position AppBar on left

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Using the React Material UI library (material-ui.com), how do you position the AppBar to the left side of the screen? The design I need to build has a the global nav (which you'd typically see across the top) along the left, with fixed position. There are also links in the nav that will slide panels out from the left (from "behind" the global nav).

I can't find anything in the documentation which supports this design. Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this using an AppBar in a flex container using `flexDirection="row"`.

```
 <React.Fragment>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Box display="flex" flexDirection="row" className={classes.root}>
        <Box flexGrow={0}>
          <AppBar elevation={0} position="sticky">
            <div>Left</div>
            <div>appBar</div>
            <Button>try me</Button>
            <Divider />
            <Button>try me2</Button>
          </AppBar>
        </Box>
        <Box display="flex" flexDirection="row" flexGrow={1}>
          <Box
            display="flex"
            flexDirection="column"
            className={classes.mainArea}
            flexGrow={1}
          ></Box>
        </Box>
        <Box flexGrow={0}>
          <AppBar elevation={0} position="sticky">
            <div>Right</div>
            <div>appBar</div>
            <Button>try me</Button>
            <Divider />
            <Button>try me2</Button>
          </AppBar>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </React.Fragment>
```

[Code SandBox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/major-viewer-layout-2-forked-001t9?file=/demo.js:4834-4852)